# Tool For Multi-Label Image Classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am currently working on a project that requires multi-label image classification. The best way to achieve this seems to be through Binary Relevance.

I was intending to use a convolutional neural net, and I've looked into scikit-multilearn on top of Keras. However, I don't see a way as to how I can load image data as a dataset into scikit-multilearn, only ARFF formatted data. Is this possible, or should I manually create the binary classifiers in Keras myself?

And if so, can Binary Relevance in Keras be implemented in parallel, or only sequentially? How does scikit-multilearn implement it?